# ERROR:Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: linux, c, syscall

решаю задачу по реализации потока , а в нем копировании содержимого одного файла в другой.Программу написал,реализовал аргументы функции через структуру.Вроде бы все по фен-шуй..Но, во-первых,компилятор недоволен,во-вторых, при непосредственном запуске программы выдает ошибку с памятью..не понимаю в чем состоит ошибка.Как такового выделения памяти не нужно, т.к. создаю файлы(открываю) посредством системных вызовов.Так же, компилятор выдает несколько предупреждений1):

1. ```
   32 line warning: passing argument 1 of ‘open’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wintconversion]
   ```
2. ```
   note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
   ```
3. ```
   35 line warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   ```
4. ```
   53 line warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   ```

Исходник:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 4096


struct thread_arg
{
    char* file, file2;
};

void * cp_sys (void * arg)
{
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];  
    struct thread_arg targ = *(struct thread_arg *) arg;

    int in,out;
    ssize_t bytes;

    

    in = open( targ.file, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT );
    if (in == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open file %s\n", targ.file);
        return NULL;
    }

    out = open( targ.file2, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0640);
    if ( out == -1 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot creat file %s\n", targ.file2);
        return NULL;
    }

    while ((bytes = read ( in, buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
        write (out , buffer, bytes );

    close (in);
    close (out);
    return NULL;
}

int main (void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int result;
    struct thread_arg targ;
    targ.file = "file.in";
    targ.file2 = "file.out";


    result = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &cp_sys, &targ);

    
    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Объясните,пожалуйста, в чем стоят ошибки данного кода.

Comment: Ошибку совю нашел, надо заменить char *file , file2  на char *file, *file2

Comment: но, появилась другая проблема: при исполнении бинарника, программа сама не завершается( копирует, все делает) , но не завершается, приходится делать ^Z чтоб остановить процесс.... с чем это связано?  я думал с зацикливанием while(1), но, когда убираю данную строку из кода перестает производиться копировние содержимого.

Comment: В соседнем вопросе я уже упомянул причину проблемы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201954/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%a2%d0%9e%d0%9a-%d0%b2-linuxpthread-create#comment2098158_1201954

Comment: Вам нужно ждать завершения потока. И ждать его не бесконечным циклом, ибо в таком случае, конечно же, произойдёт зацикливание, а функцией `pthread_join`. И вообще, прежде чем программировать потоки, стоило бы хоть пару туториалов почитать чтоли...

Comment: @V-Mor Читаю книгу Иванова программирование в Linux и потом выполняю задания преподователя по ОС.Но да, спасибо за совет, я про ютуб совсем уже позабыл..